# Which control in C++ Win32 equal with "Run" control in C# WPF?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, word-wrap

Which control in Win32 support wrap text like bellow and support mouse down event like Run in C# (as in picture below)? If there isn's have built in control, which libray I can use? Thank!

[image]

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Margin="10">
    <Run>A text run.</Run>
    <Run Background="Yellow" MouseDown="Run_MouseDown">
        <!-- Support mouse down event -->
        This is long Run that auto wrap to begin of the below line.
    </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One candidate would be the [`STATIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773.aspx) control.

Use the `SS_LEFT` style:

> A simple rectangle and left-aligns the text in the rectangle. The text is formatted before it is displayed. Words that extend past the end of a line are automatically wrapped to the beginning of the next left-aligned line. Words that are longer than the width of the control are truncated.

The parent control is sent [`STN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760784.aspx) notifications when the control is clicked.

What you cannot do with a `STATIC` control is highlight some part of the text as shown in your screenshot. To achieve that you would likely need to use [windowless rich edit controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787609.aspx).

Comment: In my question, I have 2 Run control, which I will use both to set mouse event, The second is append after the first. Static control can break line, yes, but the second line will have same start horizontal position with the first line. What I want is the second Run text break line at same horizontal start with the first Run control.

Comment: To get the appearance in that screenshot you'll want windowless rich edit.

Comment: @DavidHeffeman It looks to me that the requirement can be met with an ordinary text control with the ES_MULTILINE style.